# Как из конструктора главной формы после проверки условия правильно закрыть форму\программу?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как из конструктора главной формы после проверки условия правильно закрыть форму\программу?

При использовании this.Close(); из конструктора главной формы выскакивает исключение:

> "Необработанное исключение типа
> "System.ObjectDisposedException" в
> System.Windows.Forms.dll"

Если же использовать Application.Exit(); то вообще ничего не происходит, форма начинает загружаться как ни в чем небывало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Закрывать форму в ее же собственном конструкторе не есть хорошо, поскольку ваша форма наверняка наследуется от Form, а следовательно реализует интерфейс IDisposable. Поэтому при закрытии формы произойдет вызов Dispose для еще не созданного инстанса (вызов Close как вы изначально сказали, происходит из конструктора). Если вам вдруг очень-очень понадобилось закрыть форму практически сразу, то можете прописать логику закрытия в обработчике события Shown, к моменту его срабатывания форма уже будет создана. Например так:

```
public YourForm()
{
     // ...

    if (your_condition)
        Shown += (sender, args) => Close();        
}
```